# Lotus Sametime portlets for WebSphere Portal Server 7

Tags: websphere-portal, sametime

I am trying to integrate sametime with websphere portal server 7. I want to show the sametime chat in a portlet. I have searched the net, found "IBM Lotus Sametime Proxy Server upgrade for WebSphere Portal 7", but not sure how to proceed. Even before proceeding, did someone try this out, or is there any other better way to show sametime chat in websphere portal 7

Answer (score 0):

You must first  verify to have the entitlement for Sametime Proxy. It is not a part of Sametime Entry offering. Anyway, it's a server component. If is it installed, you can use with Portal 7, assuming you are at the right fix level

Comment: I tried to install the proxy server, but it requires system console server it seems. I am not really sure whether I can use this or not, is there any other way to show sametime contacts/chat in a portlet, in websphere portal 7

Comment: can we configure the sametime chart with portal, the sametime chart that we use in an organisation. In office, we use sametime connect for internal communication purpose, in the sametime connect we define the server community address info. But can we use the same thing in portal.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you have for Sametime, but if you entitled to Sametime Proxy Server then you should also have Sametime System Console.

What version and package of Sametime do you have?  That would go a long way toward pointing you to what you need.

Is this ST 8.5.2.1?  or ST 9.0?